# Validate if s3 bucket encryption is enabled from cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Is there any way I can find out using aws cli if encryption is enabled for the given bucket.

I tried using:

```
aws s3api get-bucket-policy --bucket my-bucket
```

and

```
aws s3api head-object --bucket YOURBUCKET --key KEYTOOBJECT
```

Not sure what key parameter should i pass.

I used : `aws s3api head-object --bucket YOURBUCKET --key AES256`

which returns me `An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found`

Comment: In S3 the "key" (in the sense of "key/value") refers to the path+filename (that's the key. The object body is the value. S3 is a key/value object store).  Encryption is not an attribute of a bucket, it's an attribute of each object.  Optionally, you can apply a policy constraint to a bucket to prevent yourself from inadvertently uploading objects without specifing that they be encrypted... but based on these things, it isn't clear exactly what you're asking about.

Answer (score 2):

As of aws cli v1.14.11 you now have the `get-bucket-encryption` option available.

```
bob$ /usr/local/bin/aws s3api get-bucket-encryption --bucket "my-bucket-name"
{
    "ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration": {
        "Rules": [
            {
                "ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault": {
                    "SSEAlgorithm": "AES256"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

[aws s3api get-bucket-encryption](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-bucket-encryption.html)